# How can I include static text in a StringVar() and still have it update to variable changes?

Tags: python, string, text, tkinter, concatenation

I would like to create a StringVar() that looks something like this:

```
someText = "The Spanish Inquisition" # Here's a normal variable whose value I will change
```

eventually

```
TkEquivalent = StringVar() # and here's the StringVar()

TkEquivalent.set(string(someText)) #and here I set it equal to the normal variable. When someText changes, this variable  will too...
```

HOWEVER:

```
TkEquivalent.set("Nobody Expects " + string(someText))
```

If I do this, the StringVar() will no longer automatically update! How can I include that static text and still have the StringVar() update to reflect changes made to someText?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There isn't enough code to give context to your question. Guessing at what you are trying to ask, Tkinter bound variables will not update until the tk main loop idles. If you are stuck in Python code, then the event loop isn't executing and no information will pass between the UI and bound variables. This is well described at at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/control-variables.html

Answer (score 4):

A StringVar does not bind with a Python name (what you'd call a variable), but with a Tkinter widget, like this:

```
a_variable= Tkinter.StringVar()
an_entry= Tkinter.Entry(textvariable=a_variable)
```

From then on, any change of `a_variable` through its `.set` method will reflect in the `an_entry` contents, and any modification of the `an_entry` contents (e.g. by the user interface) will also update the `a_variable` contents.

However, if that is not what you want, you can have two (or more) references to the same StringVar in your code:

```
var1= var2= Tkinter.StringVar()
var1.set("some text")
assert var1.get() == var2.get() # they'll always be equal
```