# How to make a tkinter appear and disappear based on a time condition

Tags: python, tkinter

The question is related to these questions:

[How do I get rid of a label in TkInter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485225/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-label-in-tkinter)

[How to make a Label appear then disappear after a certain amount of time in python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276672/how-to-make-a-label-appear-then-disappear-after-a-certain-amount-of-time-in-pyth)

I am trying to create a tkinter object where there are two labels.

First label shows a static text set.
Second label appears to show some message every configured time interval (e.g., shows a pomodoro message every 20 minutes)

I am struggling to hide the label and then make it appear again.

One option is to keep the label but turn the text as blank, but that is not useful in my case. I need the label itself to disappear completely.

Is it possible? To add a label at a set time and then disappear it again?

Here in the code I have taken a simple example to show seconds from time when it is in multiple of 5. Otherwise hide the label. I will modify it for other conditions once I understand the concept.

I have tried the below approach but either it results in variable referenced before assignment error or it keeps on adding labels one below the other without disappearing.

Code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
import time

app = Tk()
label1 = Label(app)
label1.pack()
label1.config(text='Static Text')
label2 = Label(app)
label2.pack()

def draw():
    #label2 = Label(app) #create it again after destroy()?
    #label2.pack() #pack it again after pack_forget?
    t = time.strftime('%S')
    if int(t) % 5 == 0:
        label2.config(text=t)
    else:
        #remove label code e.g. label2.pack_forget() or label2.destroy()
    label1.after(1000,draw)

draw()
app.mainloop()
```

Please help me make the question more helpful for this community, if it isn't in the requisite format.

Comment: Maybe us threading and/or time.sleep?

Comment: @KovyJacob Hey thanks for the reply. However, I need help with disappearing the label. Can you help me go in the right direction how to make the label disappear and then reappear based on a condition of time?

Comment: The question is how to kill a label? Or how to kill it after a certain amount of time.

Comment: label2.destroy() should work to destroy it, no?

Comment: It then results in an error next time if the condition is not met. Can we check if the label is present before destroying it to avoid that variable used without assignment error? Also how do we create the label again? Should I keep Label() and pack() method inside the if statement?

Comment: Maybe try elif int(t) % 5 != 0 and label2 == True instead of the else statement, or something like that.

Comment: You may have to do not None instead of == True. But I think something like that should work, to check if the label exists before you destroy it.

Comment: I may not be fully understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can also try if hasattr(draw, 'label2'): to check if label2 exists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a simple example where the label is packed every 5th second, and then removed again after 1 second. You can of course modify the duration for how long you want to view the label before it is removed again by changing the second if statement to a higher number

```py
import tkinter as tk
import time

app = tk.Tk()
label1 = tk.Label(app, text='Static Text')
label1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(app)

def draw():
    t = time.strftime('%S')

    mod5 = int(t) % 5
    if mod5 == 0:
        label2.pack()
    elif mod5 == 1:
        label2.forget()

    label2.config(text=t)
    app.after(100, draw)


draw()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @oskros ! .forget() was the thing I was looking for. I was trying destroy and pack_forget. Thanks again.

Comment: @Meet the above example would work just fine if you replace `.forget()` with `.pack_forget()`, the part responsible for making it work is putting `.pack()` inside the `.after()` loop